# Sequential algorithm for coloring graphs- there exists an ordering of vertices where it finds a coloring with $\chi(G)$ colors.

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

The sequential algorithm for coloring graphs is as follows

> 1. Put vertices in the queue $ v_1,v_2,...,v_n$ in the order of your choice.
> 2. Take out vertices from the queue and color them with the lowest color (think of colors as numbers) that's not used by their neighbours.

Meaning for example:

[image]

I need to prove that for every graph there exists an ordering of the vertices, that the algorithm finds the coloring with $\chi(G)$ colors.

Well traditionally I tried induction by the number of vertices.

When $|E(G)|=m$ our consists of a single vertex, which is colored with $1$ so all is good.

Now for the induction step.

We have a graph $G$ with $n+1$ verices. Let's take out the one with the highest degree out of it - let's name it $v$. We get a graph $G-v$. Given the proper ordering of vertices in $G-v$ the algorithm find the coloring of it with $\chi(G-v)$ colors. Obviously $\chi(G-v) \leq \chi(G)$. Now we have two cases.

Either $deg(v)<\chi(G-v)$, then we can color it with some of the colors used in $G-v$ and all is good, we can't go with less colors then $(G-v)$. Now if $deg(v)>\chi(G)$ Then let's inspect  the neighbours of $v$. If the colors that they use are not all from $G-v$ then we can also color it how we want. But if the colors they use are all of the colors used in $G-v$ then we have to add one more, which is optimal.

Is this in any way correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a minimal coloring $c:V(G)\rightarrow\{1,2,\ldots,\chi(G)\}$, simply order the vertices in the queue so that all the vertices with $c(v)=1$ come first, followed by those with $c(v)=2$, and so on.  When the vertices are removed from the queue, each will be assigned a new color $c'(v)$.  Since none of the vertices with $c(v)=1$ are adjacent to each other, they will all have $c'(v)=c(v)=1$.  Next, none of the vertices with $c(v)=2$ are adjacent to each other, so they will all have either $c'(v)=1$ (if they have no neighbors in the first batch) or $c'(v)=2$; that is, $c'(v)\le c(v)$ for $c(v)\le 2$.  And so on, by induction; we conclude that $c'(v) \le c(v)$ for all $v$.  So $c'$ has no more colors than $c$; and since $c$ was already a minimal coloring, $c'$ must have exactly $\chi(G)$ colors.